# Is it possible to run publisher and subscriber in single node under rosserial?

Tags: control, ros, arduino, rosserial, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to get input from an analog sensor and control the LED. In this case can i run both the publisher and subscriber under same node in rosserial because i have only one Arduino board. Guide me towards some similar codes written.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201942/is-it-possible-to-run-publisher-and-subscriber-in-single-node-under-rosserial?/) by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2015-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yep, absolutely common standard use case, possible without problems......

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2015-01-28**:
Can you please give me an example code where both publisher and subscriber written in same node?